# Apply different button's images based on the current theme

Tags: android, themes

I have read a lot of documentation which explain how to create themes.xml, styles.xml and attars.xml files for changing the appearance of an application by changing the theme. Most of the application have the same background image for all the buttons, and generally the same characteristics for all the components of the same type.

My problem is a little bit different. In my application I have a set of buttons, each one having its proper image (depending on its usage). In my application I have just two themes, and each button should have an image or another according to the selected theme (than each button has its proper images (two images for each button)). I don't need a general background image valid for each button.

How can I associate a button with its two images (an image for each theme)?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me

Comment: I have two images for each button in my activities. I want to select the right image for each button according to the selected theme.

Answer (score 0):

Your request suppose to be some thing very simple in Android. Just use selector for that task. You can read about it in the official [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#Style).

Reading about [themes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.Theme.html):

> This class holds the current attribute values for a particular theme.
>   In other words, a Theme is a set of values for resource attributes;
>   these are used in conjunction with TypedArray to resolve the final
>   value for an attribute.

So theme is a set of values, so you can't changed set of values according to set of values. After reading the definition even the question itself sounds weird.

Comment: With selector I can just modify the appearance of a button according to its state (pressed, highlighted, normal, etc.). Is there a way for selecting its appearance also according to the theme?

Comment: @Massimo I added a reference about themes, so it will be clear to you.

Comment: I think I can not resolve my problem this way. Themes are not enough for solving my problem.

Comment: @Massimo yep this would be my conclusion also. Try posting your real problem on a new question.

Comment: Here I found a question similar to mine. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/ZCM9lWOsFOY/SBjOxrvRc8cJ   basically they say the solution is to change images via code... Thanks however!